# replace multiple files with 1 new file

Tags: command-line

How do I replace a file called config.dat on multiple files across multiple directories?

example:

```
/var/www/site1/configs/config.dat
/var/www/site2/configs/config.dat
/var/www/site3/configs/config.dat
```

I want to replace all config.data with my new /home/john/config.dat.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and run:

```
cd /var/www
sudo find . -type f  -name 'config.dat' -exec cp /home/john/config.dat {} \;
```

Here I have assumed that the `/var/www` directory is owned by root, but if you are the owner of the `/var/www` directory, then you don't need to use `sudo` in the command.

Comment: That seems to work! What does the '{} \' at the end mean?

Comment: `-exec COMMAND \;` Carries out COMMAND on each file that find matches. The command sequence terminates with ; (the ";" is escaped to make certain the shell passes it to find literally, without interpreting it as a special character). If COMMAND contains `{}`, then find substitutes the full path name(s) of the selected file(s) for "{}".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the location of the files you want to replace follows the pattern `/var/www/*/configs/config.dat`, then execute this in a terminal:

```
for f in /var/www/*/configs/config.dat; do cp /home/john/config.dat "$f"; done
```

The for-loop iterates over the expanded list of target filenames using variable `f`. The cp-statement copies the contents of `/home/john/config.dat` over each of them.

Comment: can you explain?

Comment: @Braiam Better?